# Looping of dates december is not including

Tags: php

I would like to ask why December is skipping when you try to run the code below? Can somebody help me or explain to me why december is not included in looping? thanks

```
$date = "2013-03-31";
$d1 = explode("-",$date);
$i = 0;
while ($i < 12)
{
    $j = $d1[2];

    if(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $d1[1], $d1[0]) < $d1[2])
        $j = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $d1[1], $d1[0]) ;

    echo $d1[0]."-".$d1[1]."-".$j."<br>";

    $d1[1]++;

    if($d1[1] == 12)
    {
        $d1[0]++;
        $d1[1] = 1;
    }
    $i++;

    if($d1[1] < 10)
        $d1[1]="0".$d1[1];
}
```

Result:

```
2013-03-31
2013-04-30
2013-05-31
2013-06-30
2013-07-31
2013-08-31
2013-09-30
2013-10-31
2013-11-30
2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
```

Missing :

**2013-12-31**

Comment: `while ($i < 12)` think about it

Comment: @Dagon it is just adding another date after looping but december month is not still included in the loop.

Comment: As @Dagon said, you're only looping 11 times at most because of `while ($i < 12)`.  You need to do `while ($i <= 12)` to include the 12th iteration (December).

Comment: Hi @Axel I know what he mean. What I mean is when I make it like this ($i <= 12) its just adding another date after the loop but the month of december is still not included or skipping. why not try it to your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my fixed version:

```
<?php
$date = "2013-03-31";

$d1 = explode("-",$date);

$i = 0;

while ( $i<=12 ){

    $j = $d1[2];

    if(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$d1[1],$d1[0])<$d1[2])
        $j = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$d1[1],$d1[0]);

    echo $d1[0]."-".$d1[1]."-".$j."<br>";


    if($d1[1]==12){
        $d1[0]++;
        $d1[1] = 1;
    }else{
        $d1[1]++;
    }

    $i++;

    if($d1[1]<10)
        $d1[1] = "0".$d1[1];
}
```

basically you were dealing with the role over from 12 to 1 incorrectly.